# how to get max value of an array using math.max

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Pretty straight forward question im only new to js this is my code if it helps understand what im trying to achive

```
var highestMark=0;
var gradeAwarded;
var StudentArr= [Student];
var markArr = [mark];
var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ", "Name");
var mark = prompt("Enter Student Mark: ", 50);
var max = Math.max.apply(markArr); /* This about equal to Math.max(numbers[0], ...) or Math.max(5, 6, ..) */
var min = Math.min.apply(markArr);

if (mark < 0 || mark > 100) {
    alert("Grate out of bounds");
} else if (mark >= 83) {
    gradeAwarded = "A";
} else if (mark >= 70) {
    gradeAwarded = "B";
} else if (mark >= 50) {
    gradeAwarded = "C";
} else if (mark >= 0) {
    gradeAwarded = "F";
}
document.write(min);
```

Comment: It looks like you're using JavaScript, but you've tagged Java as well. `Java != JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

The other way todo it is to use the `Array.reduce` method

```
   var max = markArr.reduce(function(a,b){return Math.max(a,b)});
```

I'n not sure which is more efficient.